# SQL replace specific date in a select

Tags: mysql, sql

Long time reader but first time poster so apologies for any mistakes in creating a post.

I'm trying to work out the rates of sales for a product based on its time available and sales.

```
SELECT productname, datediff(day, MIN(DateAdded), getdate())/ nullif(SalesToDate,0) as [Days For A Sale]
FROM  TABLE
```

Pretty simple but it works, the problem is some old products incorrectly have dateadded as the year as 1970 in the database (eg. 1970-02-02 09:21:00.000).

Is there a way to replace the all the DateAdded in the select that include 1970 with 2012 for example? Some kind of 'case if 1970 then 2012' but for the select and not affecting other dates.

I just want it for this query, I couldn't update the dates in the database without affecting a lot. Thanks in advance and any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can use Case inside Aggregate Function as

```html
SELECT 
   productname, 
   DATEADD(YEAR, 42, datediff(day, MIN(case when year(DateAdded) = '1970'
    then  dateadd(YY,CEILING(datediff(YY,DateAdded,'1/1/2012')),DateAdded)
    else a  end ),getdate())/nullif(SalesToDate,0)) as [Days For A Sale] 
   FROM TABLE
```

Used  Celling  to round always maximum value as we are comparing with '1/1/2012'
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do it in the select, and specifically replace 1970 with 2012 then a `DATEADD` may help you out:

```
SELECT 
   productname, 
   DATEADD(YEAR, 42, datediff(day, MIN(DateAdded),getdate())/nullif(SalesToDate,0)) as [Days For A Sale] 
   FROM TABLE
```

Answer (score -1):

Hope this will work:

SELECT CONVERT(DATE,REPLACE(DATEADDED,YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADDED)),'2012')) FROM TABLE where YEAR(CONVERT(DATE,DATEADDED)) ='1970'